# What is the error in my code for advent of code day 14 part 2?

Tags: python

I am learning how to code in python so I am taking the challenge of doing advent of code, so I have an error in day 14 part 2 where it is saying Memory Error,  I have to find the answer for 846601, to see what the problem is asking https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/14, for the hidden part two look here: http://prntscr.com/lv703p.

So for the code I am using

```
recipe = ["3","7"]
position1 = 1
position2 = 0
value = 0
while value== 0:
    newrecipe = str(int(recipe[position2])+int(recipe[position1]))
    if len(newrecipe)== 1:
        recipe.append(newrecipe)
    elif len(newrecipe)== 2:
        recipe.append(newrecipe[0])
        recipe.append(newrecipe[1])
    position2= (position2 + int(recipe[position2])+1) % (len(recipe))
    position1= (position1 + int(recipe[position1])+1) % (len(recipe))
    if int(recipe[len(recipe)-6]) == 8:
        if int(recipe[len(recipe)-5]) == 4:
            if int(recipe[len(recipe)-4]) == 6:
                if int(recipe[len(recipe)-3]) == 6:
                    if int(recipe[len(recipe)-2]) == 0:
                        if int(recipe[len(recipe)-1]) == 1:

                            value = len(recipe)-5
print(value)
```

If you have any input or questions if my code is confusing you can ask.

Edit:
So using the comment I changed the code to:

```
recipe = ["3","7"]
position1 = 1
position2 = 0
value=0
while value == 0:
    newrecipe = str(int(recipe[position2])+int(recipe[position1]))
    if len(newrecipe)== 1:
        recipe.append(newrecipe)
    elif len(newrecipe)== 2:
        recipe.append(newrecipe[0])
        recipe.append(newrecipe[1])
    position2= (position2 + int(recipe[position2])+1) % (len(recipe))
    position1= (position1 + int(recipe[position1])+1) % (len(recipe))
    if len(recipe) >= 6 and recipe[-6:] == ["8", "4", "6", "6", "0", "1"]:
        value= len(recipe)-5
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of statements that starts with

```
if int(recipe[len(recipe)-6]) == 8:
```

may lead to an error if `len(recipe)` is below 6, which it probably is. You could replace that whole sequence with something like

```
if len(recipe) >= 6 and recipe[-6:] == ["8", "4", "6", "6", "0", "1"]:
    ...
```

Comment: I don't usually get a error on the below 6, it usually gets to the millions and then stops. but let me try using this line, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realised the mistake was that the max limit of strings I could was not as much as the value, once I changed it to integers in the recipe lists it worked. Thanks for the help.